# How to use Axis WSDL2Java generated files?

Tags: java, axis, wsdl2java

I generated Java files from WSDL with WSDL2Java converter, but I don't know how can I use service with these files, because there are no examples. I'm implementing client side.

Comment: Are you using Axis1 or Axis2? If it is Axis2 then which data binding option have you used? What are the exact parameters you have specified to wsdl2java?

Comment: Axis1 and I only gave option -s wsdl_filename.wsdl and of course classpath for java including all required jars

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding Axis2: read these these links they contain some examples:

http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5_1/quickstartguide.html#clients
http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_0/userguide3.html

**EDIT:** Regarding Axis1: it is based on JAX-RPC and you need to instantiate stub object or use service locator to get stub instance and all WS operations will be in that. An example is given [here](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL):

```
public class Tester {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    // Make a service
    AddressBookService service = new AddressBookServiceLocator();

    // Now use the service to get a stub which implements the SDI.
    AddressBook port = service.getAddressBook();

    // Make the actual call
    Address address = new Address(...);
    port.addEntry("Russell Butek", address);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this kind of files : ServiceBindingImpl.java
ServiceBindingStub.java
ServicePortType.java
ServiceService.java
ServiceLocator.java
...

Comment: Then just instantiate your ServiceLocator. 


<your return type here> result = new ServiceLocator().getService().<your oepration name here>(<your operation parameters here>)

Comment: For some reason ServiceLocator doesn't have getService() method. Thx for help anyway

Answer (score 3):

Normally a client doesn't instantiate a stub in Web Services, you would use the service locator and call the get method. I can't tell from your question, but if you are asking a more general "Where do I get JavaDocs (or such) to better understand the API", you would have to tell use which WS you are using.

[**Axis User Guide**](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html)