# Java AXIS2 web-service client

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to write a code to consume a web service found at:
http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=64

I've used Axis2's WSDL2Java.bat tool and had two Java files generated:

- GeoIPServiceStub.java
- GeoIPServiceCallbackHandler.java

I've imported these, as well as the axis 'lib' folder into my project.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    GeoIPServiceStub stub = new GeoIPServiceStub();

    GetGeoIP geoIP = new GetGeoIP();

    geoIP.setIPAddress("X.X.X.X");
    GetGeoIPResponse reponse = stub.getGeoIP(geoIP);
```

When I try running it, it throws an *InstantiationError*.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to instantiate an abstract class or interface. that's why InstantiationError is thrown.

As per the docs, it is stated as follows

**public class InstantiationError
extends IncompatibleClassChangeError**

*Thrown when an application tries to use the Java new construct to instantiate an abstract class or an interface.Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.*

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. I think I'm not initializing "stub" the way I am supposed to. Any ideas?

Comment: You are welcome, Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665595/how-to-use-axis-wsdl2java-generated-files and read the links provided

Comment: Okay, it works.. sorta. Every once in a while I get _NullPointerException_ thrown at me. When I do a _printStackTrace()_ I get the following: **"Unable to locate a valid EngineConfigurationFactory"**

Comment: Please accept my answer. that's probably another question. but, i will help you. I did some search and found this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2897). It seems to be an open bug in axis

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks a lot!